# How to display values from multiple models using ViewModel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I need one table in View that contains data from my ViewModel which contains references to two models. 
So: 
I have `StudentModel`, `ClassModel` and a `StudentClassViewModel`.

What should I do in controller and view to correctly display all properties from student AND connected class model? Anything please.

This are my models (I'm using code first)

```
public class Class
{
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }   
    public ICollection<Student> Student { get; set; }
}
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; } 
    public Class Class { get; set; }
    public int ClassId { get; set; }

}
public class StudentClassViewModel
{
    public Class Class { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You should be more precise in order for others to help you. Can you share the code of your controller to see what you already tried and what difficulty you are facing ?

Comment: That ViewModel should not include DB/Entity models. So advice to do mapping and just add properties in Viewmodel that you need. Do not send Entity models to View.

Comment: Yeah, sorry for not providing enough information, but the answer from @SwapnilVishwakarma helped!  I just adjusted it for list of students and list of classes.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would have done it.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //can be fetched from database or your own custom implementation
            Class myClass = new Class()
            {
                ClassId = 1,
                Name = "Class 1"
            };
            Student myStudent = new Student()
            {
                Class = myClass,
                ClassId = 1,
                Name = "John Doe",
                StudentId = 1
            };
            StudentClassViewModel studentClassViewModel = new StudentClassViewModel()
            {
                Class = myClass,
                Student = myStudent
            };
            return View(studentClassViewModel);
        }


    }
```

View:

```
@model stackoverflow.Models.StudentClassViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr><td>Student ID</td><td>Student Name</td><td>Class ID</td><td>Class Name</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@Model.Student.StudentId</td>
            <td>@Model.Student.Name</td>
            <td>@Model.Student.Class.ClassId</td>
            <td>@Model.Student.Class.Name</td>
        </tr>

        <!--OR-->

        <tr>
            <td>@Model.Student.StudentId</td>
            <td>@Model.Student.Name</td>
            <td>@Model.Class.ClassId</td>
            <td>@Model.Class.Name</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```